# String comparision not working in shell script

Tags: string, shell, unix

I have written a simple shell script to do some automation work. Basically the script searches for all the files in the current path and if the file is a specified one, it does some action.
Below are the relevant lines ---

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `ls *`
do
if [$i =="ls.sh"] 
then .... //do something
fi
done
```

However, the string comparision in line 3 is not working and I am getting this when I run the script   --

```
./ls.sh: line 3: [scripth.sh: command not found
./ls.sh: line 3: [scripth.sh~: command not found
./ls.sh: line 3: [test.sh: command not found
```

What is the correction to be done ?

Comment: Since you want to do something if `ls.sh` exists, why not simply write: `if [ -f ls.sh ] ; then ...do something...; fi`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems.

In line 1, you are not doing what you think you are.   You should put a backquote around ls *:

```
for i in `ls *`
```

That will go through all files that list in the current directory.  Your line will not run any command, but instead it will use * to get all files and your list will include a word "ls" at the front.

try this from a command line:

```
echo ls *
echo `ls *`
```

You might just want to do:

```
for i in *
```

Second problem.  Put spaces inside your square brackets:

```
[ $i == "ls.sh" ]
```

The spaces are necessary.

Third problem.  Use one = for string comparison

```
[ $i = "ls.sh" ]
```

Comment: +1: Good answer. Given the formatting you saw, your diagnosis about the necessary backticks was correct. Once the question was formatted, your comment there became inaccurate.  Not your fault - I'm noting this so that the trigger-happy don't down-vote you.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I had the same problem entering backticks but didn't think about them not being in the question for the same reason.

Answer (score 3):

first of all, don't use `ls` like that. It will go bonkers if your files have spaces!.
Use shell expansion. Then, you can use `case/esac` to make string comparison. (or if/else)

```
for file in *
do
  case "$file" in
    "ls.sh" ) echo "do something"
     ;;
  esac
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Use: `if [ "$i" = "ls.sh" ]` - notice the spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You have not included a space after `==`, so your code should actually be:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `ls *`
do
    if [ $i == "ls.sh" ] 
    then 
        //do something
    fi
done
```

Comment: You also need spaces to separate the `[` command name from its arguments.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to check the existing of a file, you could do it directly in shell.

```
if [ -e ls.sh ]
then 
  # ... do something
fi
```